# Simple audio editor (to double the volume and cut)

Tags: gratis, audio-editing

I want to painlessly double the volume of and cut up audio files, for free on Windows 10 and/or Ubuntu.

Audacity does the latter, but I'm overwhelmed attempting the first.

Comment: Please add more details. Free? OS?

Comment: Audacity: `Effects / Amplify` by `+6 db` should double the volume. IMHO, `Effects / Normalize` does a better job since you typically cannot rely on an starting volume. Normalize defines the output volume instead of acting on the input volume.

Comment: @Thomas To actually double the acoustic volume (Sound Pressure Level), an increase of 3dB would be correct. 6dB would double the voltages at the speaker/headphones, which, together with the also doubled current, causes a 4 times higher energy output. At the end however, Normalize would be a better option anyway, exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: @Marcel: thanks for the explanation. Seems I did it wrong all the time...

Answer (score 4):

A nice, free, lightweight audio editor that is not audacity is [Wavosaur](http://www.wavosaur.com). It allows you to cut, move, and edit the volume of audio files. Cutting is simply done using standard cut/copy/paste commands, and volume is done via the process menu.

Best of all, the largest version is only just over a megabyte!